# Как сменитть версию платформы vs c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку TDLib , но при установке появляется такая ошибка. Как можно исправить ? (вижу, что не подходит версия платформы, но понятия не имею как сменить ее на нужную)[image: скриншот ошибки]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: пробовал все версии, что на скрине. со всеми такая ошибка

Comment: ¿Почему в тегах С++?